# Login to twitter from settings in iOS is not working

Tags: ios5, twitter

I am experiencing some issue in logging into the twitter in iOS via settings app. I am tring to add accounts in settings but app doesn't allow to make a successful login despite typing correct user name and password. I did check with multiple accounts, but not working. Any issues in twitter framework in iOS?

Thanks,